# API 11 ActionBar menuItems covering title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have a menu xml defined with items having android:showAsAction="ifRoom". Is there a way to use "ifRoom" and have the title be considered? I want as many items to fit without them covering the title.

When all items have "ifRoom"
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL9Dx.png)

When only first item has "ifRoom"
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0RDn.png)

Comment: In short no. Your best bet is to implement a custon title.

Comment: Thank you, not what I was hoping for but it was the straight-forward type of answer I wanted